# A generalization of toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $M$ be a monoid with cancelation whose groupification is $\mathbb Z^d$ ($d$ finite). Even without assuming a finite generation of $M$, it seems to me that
(a) $X=Spec\, \mathbb C M$ contains the algebraic torus $T=(\mathbb C^*)^d$
(b) $X$ is the Zariski closure of $T$, and
(c) $T$'s action on itself extends to one on $X$.

Am I wrong?

Is such generalized (non-affine, non-projective) concept of toric variety considered in literature?

Comment: Maybe Howard Thompson's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306221v1 ?